# Toggle visibility of an in-page Angular Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I have a bookmarklet that I am migrating over to a Chrome extension. It is an Angular application. Currently it uses a [browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) and a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) to allow the user to invoke injection of the application into the page.

Once injected into the page, the extension should allow the user to click on the browser action again to toggle visibility of the interface. Currently, clicking on the browser action more than once sees the background script attempt to re-inject all the JavaScript files into the page, throwing errors like this:

> WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once

How can I maintain some state in the background script that will allow toggling of the injected interface without having it perform initialisation of the extension each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Manifest

Before we get stuck in, we need to configure the Chrome extension such that it has...

1. access to the active tab with permission `activeTab`,
2. a list of `web_accessible_resources` (scripts and stylesheets) the extension will inject,
3. access to `webNavigation` events so that we know when the user has refreshed or navigated within a tab,
4. and a background script defined under property `background.scripts`.

Let's see what this looks like in the actual `manifest.json` file*:

```
// manifest.json

"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"web_accessible_resources": [
    "angular.min.js",
    "jquery.min.js",
    "main.js",
    "style.css"
],

"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "webNavigation",
    "http://*/*"
]
```

**partial manifest.json shown*

______

### State for the life of a tab

It is possible to maintain state (e.g. has the browser action been clicked) for the life of a single tab similarly to how you might maintain state in other situations, by maintaining a hash of the `id` subject's and their session data. In this instance, the subject is a tab. We have access to a tab's `id` from within a click handler of the browser action. For example:

```
// background.js

var clicked = {};

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    clicked[tab.id] = (clicked[tab.id] || 0) + 1;
});
```

The state of a tab will persist across navigation to other web pages so we also need to listen for an event that tells us navigation has occurred, meaning the extension no longer exists in the page, and reset the tab's state:

```
// background.js continued
// Reset state of our tab data when the page is refreshed

chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function (details) {
    clicked[details.tabId] = 0;
});
```

______

### Conditional script injection (`background.js`)

Using the above example we can perform conditional injection of scripts into the page by storing a boolean value that indicates if the extension has already been initialised on the active tab. On initialisation we want to inject *all* scripts required, and on subsequent calls to action only our own client script - let's say we have a file `main.js` that constitutes the extensions own payload (it does not contain vendor scripts which should only be injected once):

```
// background.js

var initialised = {};

chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function (details) {
    initialised[details.tabId] = false;
});

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {

    // When extension already exists in page, load
    // a script that will toggle the interface
    if (initialised[tab.id]) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'main.js'});
        return;
    }

    // Mark this tab as 'initialised'
    initialised[tab.id] = true;

    var javascripts = [
        "jquery.min.js",
        "angular.min.js",
        "main.js"
    ];

    var stylesheets = [
        "style.css"
    ];

    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < javascripts.length; i++) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: javascripts[i]});
    }

    for (i = 0; i < stylesheets.length; i++) {
        chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {file: stylesheets[i]});
    }
});
```

______

### Toggle or initialise extension via injected script (`main.js`)

When injection is complete we will be in one of two positions:

1. The extension requires complete initialisation as it is the first time the user has invoked it on the active tab. (*In this case, all vendor files **and** the client script will be injected.*)
2. The extension should be toggled in or out of view. (*In this case, only the client script will have been injected.*)

Initialising the extension should be done by declaring the module and inserting all templates, etc. (If the extension is entirely custom, perform initialisation however you see fit.)

Our `main.js` file should therefore do the following:

1. Look for a global flag (e.g. `_my_chrome_extension`) that indicates the extension already exists within the page.
2. If the flag exists:

   1. Get the scope of the Angular application and retrieve a property `isVisible` (or similar).
   2. Set the flag to the opposite of its current value (`isVisible = !isVisible`).
3. If the flag does not exist:

   1. Bootstrap the Angular application.
   2. In the Angular app (e.g. in a `run` block or similar) set the property `isVisible` to be true so that the interface appears automatically.

And a code example...

```
// main.js

(function (angular, $) {
    var scope;

    // Check if application exists in page already    
    if (typeof window['_my_chrome_extension'] !== 'undefined') {
        var elem = document.querySelector('._extension_container');
        scope = angular.element(elem).scope();
    }

    if (scope) {

        // TOGGLE VISIBILITY

        scope.isVisible = !scope.isVisible;
        scope.$applyAsync();

    } else {

        window['_my_chrome_extension'] = true;

        // PERFORM INITIALISATION

        // ANGULAR APP GOES HERE

    }
})(angular, jQuery);
```

As a quick aside, in your template you will need something like the following which shows/hides the interface according to the value of `isVisible`:

```
// template.html

<div id="_my_chrome_extension" ng-show="isVisible"></div>
```